# Docker container refuses to get killed after run command turns into a zombie

Tags: linux, docker, zombie-process, lxc

first thing first. my system info and versions:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.04
Release:    13.04
Codename:   raring

$ sudo docker version
Client version: 0.9.0
Go version (client): go1.2.1
Git commit (client): 2b3fdf2
Server version: 0.9.0
Git commit (server): 2b3fdf2
Go version (server): go1.2.1

$ lxc-version
lxc version: 0.9.0

$ uname -a
Linux ip-10-0-2-86 3.8.0-19-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 17 18:16:28 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am not able to stop a container after the process inside of it becomes a zombie. After upgrading to to docker 0.9.0 I was seeing tons of zombies on my server. example:

```
$ ps axo stat,ppid,pid,comm | grep -w defunct
Zl   25327 25332 node <defunct>

$ pstree -p
init(1)─┬
        ├─sh(819)───docker(831)─┬
                                ├─lxc-start(25327)───node(25332)───{node}(25378)
```

I can see that  `lxc-start(25327)` not calling wait() on the node process 25332 keeping to zombie alive. So I checked what it was doing with strace and it seemed to be stuck on a `epoll_wait`. stract actually gets stuck at first and just shows this:

```
$sudo strace -ir -ttt -T -v -p 25327
Process 25327 attached - interrupt to quit (when asked to kill)
     0.000103 [    7fe59b9d34b3] epoll_wait(8,
```

but after I run a sudo docker kill 3da5764b7bc9358 I get more output:

```
 0.000103 [    7fe59b9d34b3] epoll_wait(8, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=21673408, u64=21673408}}}, 10, 4294967295) = 1 <8.935002>
 8.935097 [    7fe59bcaff60] accept(4, 0, NULL) = 9 <0.000035>
 0.000095 [    7fe59bcafeb3] fcntl(9, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0 <0.000027>
 0.000083 [    7fe59b9d401a] setsockopt(9, SOL_SOCKET, SO_PASSCRED, [1], 4) = 0 <0.000027>
 0.000089 [    7fe59b9d347a] epoll_ctl(8, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 9, {EPOLLIN, {u32=21673472, u64=21673472}}) = 0 <0.000023>
 0.000087 [    7fe59b9d34b3] epoll_wait(8, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=21673472, u64=21673472}}}, 10, 4294967295) = 1 <0.000026>
 0.000090 [    7fe59bcb0130] recvmsg(9, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8}], msg_controllen=32, {cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS{pid=773, uid=0, gid=0}}, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 8 <0.000034>
 0.000128 [    7fe59bcb019d] sendto(9, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\364b\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 24, 0, NULL, 0) = 24 <0.000029>
 0.000090 [    7fe59b9d34b3] epoll_wait(8, {{EPOLLIN|EPOLLHUP, {u32=21673472, u64=21673472}}}, 10, 4294967295) = 1 <0.000018>
 0.000091 [    7fe59bcb0130] recvmsg(9, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8}], msg_controllen=32, {cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS{pid=0, uid=0, gid=0}}, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 0 <0.000026>
 0.000122 [    7fe59b9d347a] epoll_ctl(8, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, 9, NULL) = 0 <0.000037>
 0.000084 [    7fe59bcafd00] close(9) = 0 <0.000048>
 0.000103 [    7fe59b9d34b3] epoll_wait(8, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=21673408, u64=21673408}}}, 10, 4294967295) = 1 <1.091839>
 1.091916 [    7fe59bcaff60] accept(4, 0, NULL) = 9 <0.000035>
 0.000093 [    7fe59bcafeb3] fcntl(9, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0 <0.000027>
 0.000083 [    7fe59b9d401a] setsockopt(9, SOL_SOCKET, SO_PASSCRED, [1], 4) = 0 <0.000026>
 0.000090 [    7fe59b9d347a] epoll_ctl(8, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 9, {EPOLLIN, {u32=21673504, u64=21673504}}) = 0 <0.000032>
 0.000100 [    7fe59b9d34b3] epoll_wait(8, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=21673504, u64=21673504}}}, 10, 4294967295) = 1 <0.000028>
 0.000088 [    7fe59bcb0130] recvmsg(9, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8}], msg_controllen=32, {cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS{pid=774, uid=0, gid=0}}, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 8 <0.000030>
 0.000125 [    7fe59bcb019d] sendto(9, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\364b\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 24, 0, NULL, 0) = 24 <0.000032>
 0.000119 [    7fe59b9d34b3] epoll_wait(8, {{EPOLLIN|EPOLLHUP, {u32=21673504, u64=21673504}}}, 10, 4294967295) = 1 <0.000071>
 0.000139 [    7fe59bcb0130] recvmsg(9, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8}], msg_controllen=32, {cmsg_len=28, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_CREDENTIALS{pid=0, uid=0, gid=0}}, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 0 <0.000018>
 0.000112 [    7fe59b9d347a] epoll_ctl(8, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, 9, NULL) = 0 <0.000028>
 0.000076 [    7fe59bcafd00] close(9) = 0 <0.000027>
 0.000096 [    7fe59b9d34b3] epoll_wait(8,
```

then I looked at what epoll_wait was waiting which looks like file 8 (i am guessing this from `epoll_wait(8, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=21673408, u64=21673408}}}, 10, 4294967295) = 1 <8.935002>` which is of the form `int epoll_wait(int epfd, struct epoll_event *events, int maxevents, int timeout);`

```
$ cat /proc/25327/fdinfo/8
pos:    0
flags:  02000002
tfd:        7 events:       19 data:          14ab830
tfd:        4 events:       19 data:          14ab5c0
```

also adding 7 and 4 based on tfd above (not sure what tfd really means)

```
$ cat /proc/25327/fdinfo/4
pos:    0
flags:  02000002
$ cat /proc/25327/fdinfo/7
pos:    0
flags:  02000002
sigmask:    fffffffe7ffbfab7
$ cd /proc/25327/fd
$ ls -al
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Mar 13 22:28 0 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 13 22:28 1 -> /dev/pts/17
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 13 22:28 2 -> /dev/pts/17
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 13 22:28 3 -> /var/log/lxc/3da5764b7bc935896a72abc9371ce68d4d658d8c70b56e1090aacb631080ec0e.log
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 13 22:28 4 -> socket:[48415]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 14 00:03 5 -> /dev/ptmx
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 14 00:03 6 -> /dev/pts/18
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 14 00:03 7 -> anon_inode:[signalfd]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 14 00:03 8 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
```

info about socket:

```
$ sudo netstat -anp | grep 48415
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name    Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     48415    25327/lxc-start     @/var/lib/lxc/3da5764b7bc935896a72abc9371ce68d4d658d8c70b56e1090aacb631080ec0e/command
```

there does seem to be a common pattern in the docker.log all containers that do not stop have this signature:

```
2014/03/16 16:33:15 Container beb71548b3b23ba3337ca30c6c2efcbfcaf19d4638cf3d5ec5b8a3e4c5f1059a failed to exit within 0 seconds of SIGTERM - using the force
2014/03/16 16:33:25 Container SIGKILL failed to exit within 10 seconds of lxc-kill beb71548b3b2 - trying direct SIGKILL
```

At this point I have no idea what to do next. any suggestions on how I can find out what is causing these containers not exit? Any other data I should collect? I also sent a SIGCHLD to this process with no avail.

more data: 
added log to end of the node process we start using the start command in the container:

```
Mon Mar 17 2014 20:52:52 GMT+0000 (UTC) process: main process = exit code: 0
```

and here are logs from docker:

```
2014/03/17 20:52:52 Container f8a3d55e0f... failed to exit within 0 seconds of SIGTERM - using the force
2014/03/17 20:53:02 Container SIGKILL failed to exit within 10 seconds of lxc-kill f8a3d55e0fd8 - trying direct SIGKILL
```

timestamps show process exited @ 20:52:52

This happens using both native and lxc docker drivers.

EDIT: REPRO STEPS!

turn this into a bash script and run and watch almost 50% of the containers turn into zombies!

```
CNT=0
while true
do 
  echo $CNT
  DOCK=$(sudo docker run -d -t anandkumarpatel/zombie_bug ./node index.js)
  sleep 60 && sudo docker stop $DOCK > out.log &
  sleep 1
  CNT=$(($CNT+1))
  if [[ "$CNT" == "50" ]]; then
    exit
  fi
done
```

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of data; thanks for gathering all this. I just have one more request: could you add your kernel version?

Comment: sorry, missed one thing:
`$ uname -a
Linux ip-10-0-2-86 3.8.0-19-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 17 18:16:28 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Can you reproduce this consistently? If yes, can you provide a Dockerfile that exhibits the behavior?

Comment: this does not repro consistently it happens 55 times out of 370 and only on our production systems which is exactly like our testing systems just missing the user load.

Comment: But there is a common pattern in the logs: 
`2014/03/16 16:33:15 Container beb71548b3b23ba3337ca30c6c2efcbfcaf19d4638cf3d5ec5b8a3e4c5f1059a failed to exit within 0 seconds of SIGTERM - using the force
2014/03/16 16:33:25 Container SIGKILL failed to exit within 10 seconds of lxc-kill beb71548b3b2 - trying direct SIGKILL`

Comment: added more info. looks like process does exit but docker does not agree?

Comment: update with repro instructions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

changing to latest kernel fixes the issue

found exact kernel difference: 
REPRO: linux-image-3.8.0-31-generic 
NO REPRO: linux-image-3.8.0-32-generic

I think this is the fix:

```
+++ linux-3.8.0/kernel/pid_namespace.c
@@ -181,6 +181,7 @@
    int nr;
    int rc;
    struct task_struct *task, *me = current;
+   int init_pids = thread_group_leader(me) ? 1 : 2;

    /* Don't allow any more processes into the pid namespace */
    disable_pid_allocation(pid_ns);
@@ -230,7 +231,7 @@
     */
    for (;;) {
        set_current_state(TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE);
-       if (pid_ns->nr_hashed == 1)
+       if (pid_ns->nr_hashed == init_pids)
            break;
        schedule();
    }
```

which came from here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/fa.linux.kernel/u4b3n4oYDQ4/GuLrXfDIYggJ

going to upgrade all our servers which repro this and see if it still occurs.

Comment: I have the issue reproducing on `Linux ring-agent-7.labs.intellij.net 3.14.0-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Mar 31 12:32:23 EDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`, docker run command stuck on epoll_wait(4,...)

Answer (score 1):

Observing not killable Docker container on SLES 12 SP 1 (was running since 3 weeks)

On `docker exec -it` command following error message:

> *rpc error: code = 13 desc = invalid header field value "oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process
>   caused \"process_linux.go:83: executing setns process caused \\"exit
>   status 16\\"\"\n"*

Linux kernel: 3.12.62-60.64.8-default

Docker version 1.12.2, build 8eab29e

Comment: Could you paste the while exec command? Ensure you have the shell you are trying to create installed on the image. (Example some docker images do  not have bash therefore will not start

Comment: Unfortunately not; I used bash and in that image normally I run bash scripts which run through, then container ist destroyed (Jenkins job). But once the removal of the container got stuck; do not know how to reproduce. I think it would be nice to have more informative error message statements giving the user more hints if possible