# INFO: task v8:SweeperThrea:<pid> blocked for more than 120 seconds

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, linux-kernel, v8

when running node a simple node process in container I see this in my kernel log and the process becomes defunct:

```
Mar 21 19:07:08 ip-10-0-2-233 kernel: [26336450.745710] INFO: task v8:SweeperThrea:2569 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Mar 21 19:07:08 ip-10-0-2-233 kernel: [26336450.745717] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
Mar 21 19:07:08 ip-10-0-2-233 kernel: [26336450.745723] v8:SweeperThrea D 0000000000000000     0  2569   2470 0x00000002
Mar 21 19:07:08 ip-10-0-2-233 kernel: [26336450.745727]  ffff8801d228fca8 0000000000000246 ffff8801d0fb1740 ffff8801d228ffd8
Mar 21 19:07:08 ip-10-0-2-233 kernel: [26336450.745730]  ffff8801d228ffd8 ffff8801d228ffd8 ffffffff81c15440 ffff8801d0fb1740
Mar 21 19:07:08 ip-10-0-2-233 kernel: [26336450.745737]  ffff8801d0fb1740 ffff8801d02f8878 0000000000000002 ffff8801d0fb1740
Mar 21 19:07:08 ip-10-0-2-233 kernel: [26336450.745741] Call Trace:
Mar 21 19:07:08 ip-10-0-2-233 kernel: [26336450.745745]  [<ffffffff816ca029>] schedule+0x29/0x70
Mar 21 19:07:08 ip-10-0-2-233 kernel: [26336450.745748]  [<ffffffff810d1365>] zap_pid_ns_processes+0x125/0x180
Mar 21 19:07:08 ip-10-0-2-233 kernel: [26336450.745752]  [<ffffffff8105e91c>] do_exit+0x85c/0x9d0
Mar 21 19:07:08 ip-10-0-2-233 kernel: [26336450.745755]  [<ffffffff8105eb0f>] do_group_exit+0x3f/0xa0
Mar 21 19:07:08 ip-10-0-2-233 kernel: [26336450.745759]  [<ffffffff8106e571>] get_signal_to_deliver+0x1c1/0x610
Mar 21 19:07:08 ip-10-0-2-233 kernel: [26336450.745764]  [<ffffffff8101439f>] do_signal+0x3f/0x8d0
Mar 21 19:07:08 ip-10-0-2-233 kernel: [26336450.745767]  [<ffffffff810f3427>] ? call_rcu_sched+0x17/0x20
Mar 21 19:07:08 ip-10-0-2-233 kernel: [26336450.745771]  [<ffffffff8108429f>] ? __put_cred+0x3f/0x50
Mar 21 19:07:08 ip-10-0-2-233 kernel: [26336450.745775]  [<ffffffff810843b9>] ? abort_creds+0x29/0x30
Mar 21 19:07:08 ip-10-0-2-233 kernel: [26336450.745779]  [<ffffffff81014cb0>] do_notify_resume+0x80/0xb0
Mar 21 19:07:08 ip-10-0-2-233 kernel: [26336450.745781]  [<ffffffff816d3a9a>] int_signal+0x12/0x17
```

more info:
docker is doing a SIGTERM then SIGKILL on the process.

docker -d -D logs:

```
[debug] server.go:924 Calling POST /containers/create
2014/03/21 19:04:11 POST /v1.10/containers/create
[/var/lib/docker|90a3fa34] +job create()
[/var/lib/docker|90a3fa34] -job create() = OK (0)
[debug] server.go:924 Calling POST /containers/{name:.*}/start
2014/03/21 19:04:11 POST /v1.10/containers/074dda12cb039f688777e2cb5115dd0c5088f6b93ed21586782cfe4e57533766/start
[/var/lib/docker|90a3fa34] +job start(074dda12cb039f688777e2cb5115dd0c5088f6b93ed21586782cfe4e57533766)
[/var/lib/docker|90a3fa34] +job allocate_interface(074dda12cb039f688777e2cb5115dd0c5088f6b93ed21586782cfe4e57533766)
[/var/lib/docker|90a3fa34] -job allocate_interface(074dda12cb039f688777e2cb5115dd0c5088f6b93ed21586782cfe4e57533766) = OK (0)
[/var/lib/docker|90a3fa34] -job start(074dda12cb039f688777e2cb5115dd0c5088f6b93ed21586782cfe4e57533766) = OK (0)
[debug] server.go:924 Calling POST /containers/{name:.*}/stop
2014/03/21 19:04:16 POST /v1.10/containers/074dda12cb039f688777e2cb5115dd0c5088f6b93ed21586782cfe4e57533766/stop?t=10
[/var/lib/docker|90a3fa34] +job stop(074dda12cb039f688777e2cb5115dd0c5088f6b93ed21586782cfe4e57533766)
2014/03/21 19:04:26 Container 074dda12cb039f688777e2cb5115dd0c5088f6b93ed21586782cfe4e57533766 failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM - using the force
2014/03/21 19:04:36 Container SIGKILL failed to exit within 10 seconds of lxc-kill 074dda12cb03 - trying direct SIGKILL
```

pstree:

```
docker(2387)─node(2532)─{node}(2569)
```

ps aux

```
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
4 S     0  2387  2386  0  80   0 - 153471 futex_ pts/0   00:00:07 docker
4 Z     0  2532  2387  0  80   0 -     0 exit   ?        00:00:00 node <defunct>
```

no files in `/proc/2532/fd`
no files in `/proc/2532//task/2569/fd/`

stack from `/proc/2532/stack`

```
[<ffffffff8105e763>] do_exit+0x6a3/0x9d0
[<ffffffff8105eb0f>] do_group_exit+0x3f/0xa0
[<ffffffff8105eb87>] sys_exit_group+0x17/0x20
[<ffffffff816d37dd>] system_call_fastpath+0x1a/0x1f
[<ffffffffffffffff>] 0xffffffffffffffff
```

stack from `/proc/2532/task/2569/stack`

```
[<ffffffff810d1365>] zap_pid_ns_processes+0x125/0x180
[<ffffffff8105e91c>] do_exit+0x85c/0x9d0
[<ffffffff8105eb0f>] do_group_exit+0x3f/0xa0
[<ffffffff8106e571>] get_signal_to_deliver+0x1c1/0x610
[<ffffffff8101439f>] do_signal+0x3f/0x8d0
[<ffffffff81014cb0>] do_notify_resume+0x80/0xb0
[<ffffffff816d3a9a>] int_signal+0x12/0x17
[<ffffffffffffffff>] 0xffffffffffffffff
```

the repro script:

```
CNT=0
while true
do 
  echo $CNT
  DOCK=$(sudo docker run -d -t anandkumarpatel/zombie_bug ./node index.js)
  sleep 60 && sudo docker stop $DOCK > out.log &
  sleep 1
  CNT=$(($CNT+1))
  if [[ "$CNT" == "50" ]]; then
    exit
  fi
done
```

strace of docker deamon during a failed kill can be found on pastebin:

```
http://pastebin.com/HxDwiRBW
```

my system info and versions. I am using custom build docker but it is forked form 0.9.0 release with 2 small patches. but this will also repro on clean 0.9.0 release.

```
$  lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.04
Release:    13.04
Codename:   raring

$ sudo docker version
Client version: 0.9.0
Go version (client): go1.2.1
Git commit (client): 70f72ea
Server version: 0.9.0
Git commit (server): 70f72ea
Go version (server): go1.2.1
Last stable version: 0.9.0

$ uname -a
Linux ip-10-0-2-233 3.8.0-19-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 1 16:35:23 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

HOWEVER, this does not repo on every system! for some reason it only repros on our production servers and one other server. they all have similar configs but same ubuntu version.

Let me know if there is more info to gather and I will grab it. I have near 100% repro rate on a test system so I can gather whatever is needed.

related: 
https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/4811

[Docker container refuses to get killed after run command turns into a zombie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413563/docker-container-refuses-to-get-killed-after-run-command-turns-into-a-zombie)

Changing to newer kernel does not repo this issue:
does not repro: linux-image-3.8.0-35-generic
Repros with linux-image-3.8.0-19-generic

will do a search to see when this gets fixed to see if it helps find root cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing to latest kernel fixes the issue

found exact kernel difference:
REPRO: linux-image-3.8.0-31-generic
NO REPRO: linux-image-3.8.0-32-generic

I think this is the fix:

```
+++ linux-3.8.0/kernel/pid_namespace.c
@@ -181,6 +181,7 @@
    int nr;
    int rc;
    struct task_struct *task, *me = current;
+   int init_pids = thread_group_leader(me) ? 1 : 2;

    /* Don't allow any more processes into the pid namespace */
    disable_pid_allocation(pid_ns);
@@ -230,7 +231,7 @@
     */
    for (;;) {
        set_current_state(TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE);
-       if (pid_ns->nr_hashed == 1)
+       if (pid_ns->nr_hashed == init_pids)
            break;
        schedule();
    }
```

which came from here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/fa.linux.kernel/u4b3n4oYDQ4/GuLrXfDIYggJ

going to upgrade all our servers which repro this and see if it still occurs.